# In shared preference, when call editor.clear() method, It delete only values or delete key value pairs

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Using shared preference, when I call editor.clear(),
It delete only values (means that keys are available) or it delete key value pair.

check the following code.

```
SharedPreferences userlogindetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edituserlogindetails = userlogindetails.edit();                
edituserlogindetails.clear();//**it delete values or key value pairs.**
edituserlogindetails.apply();
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Mark in the editor to remove all values from the preferences. references : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()

Comment: No, you must be getting the default values in each case which are returned even if the keys aren't available.

Comment: If you see the SharedPreference File then contains key value pair to precise data is stored in xml format wherein keys form tags. Either you use clear or remove. It removes the Key-Value pair basically an xml tag. Clear is used to delete all values while Remove is used to delete individual value

Answer (score 2):

According to [SharedPreferences.Editor#remove](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) you have to call `remove()`

> **remove**
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> SharedPreferences.Editor remove (String key)
>
> Mark in the editor that a preference value should be removed, which will be done in the actual preferences once commit() is called.
>
> Note that when committing back to the preferences, all removals are done first, regardless of whether you called remove before or after put methods on this editor.

Here is an example

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.remove("key"); //Your key here
editor.apply();
```

Comment: I think my question not understand you. when clear method call , It delete values or it delete key value pairs in shared preference.

Comment: Sorry but remove is used to delete individual key value pair and Clear is user to delete all. I recommend to verify it. As remove takes KEY as the input

Answer (score 2):

It deletes/clears all the values of your shared preferences. And if you want to remove the key you have to use remove as mentioned in the answer by Michele.

Comment: Sorry but remove is used to delete individual key value pair and Clear is user to delete all. I recommend to verify it. As remove takes KEY as the input

Comment: But clear doesn't delete the key. And the question is about what does clear do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add ".commit()" as like this

```
sharedPreference?.edit()?.clear()?.commit()
```